# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywhatkit'

Tags: python, ide, spyder, modulenotfounderror

I'm use 2 python IDE's in my system one is spyder and another one is python IDLE whenever I import a module in spyder it works the same code doesn't works in python IDLE it shows error.

Comment: How did you install pywhatkit in spyder ? I think the error can be that spyder is running python in a virtual environnement so the lib here aren't share with the default python IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the pywhatkit on the local machine from the pip method?

```
pip install pywhatkit
```

try to locate the package in this dir,
like these  *C:\Users\charan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\*  , or the python path.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem but this fixed it pip3 install flask

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

install pywhatkit using this command ( py -m pip install pywhatkit )